# Android XML - Trying to hide remove "preference" option

Tags: android, xml

Trying to hide the "DisableGMS" option but dont know where to put the code or how to use it, there arent many examples that i can find online on how to implement "removePreference". everyone just say use "removePreference" but no implementation examples on how its used in the code or where its put. Can someone please put it in for me?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ListPreference android:entries="@array/LockScreenEffectName" android:title="Unlock effect settings" android:key="lockscreen_effect" android:summary="Set the phone to unlock effect" android:entryValues="@array/LockScreenEffectValue"/>
    <SwitchPreference android:title="Moon calendar lock screen settings" android:key="lockscreen_showmoon" android:summary="It is displayed on the moon lock screen" android:summaryOn="moon lock screen has been enabled" android:summaryOff="moon lock screen has been disabled"/>
    <SwitchPreference android:title="Lock screen clock shows seconds" android:key="aurora_lockscreen_seconds" android:summary="Second display on the lock screen" android:summaryOn="Lock screen has been displayed in seconds" android:summaryOff="Lock screen has hidden seconds"/>
    <EditTextPreference android:title="Custom lock screen operator name" android:key="CarrierText_Keyguard" android:summary="Lock screen will display the operator name custom name" android:dialogTitle="Please enter the custom lock screen operator name"/>
    <ListPreference android:entries="@array/SettingName" android:title="System Settings Style" android:key="listui" android:summary="Setting your favorite style system settings" android:entryValues="@array/SettingValue"/>
    <SwitchPreference android:title="WIFI signal optimization" android:key="WifiManager" android:summary="WIFI signal optimization" android:summaryOn="It has opened WIFI Optimization" android:summaryOff="WIFI optimization has been closed"/>
    <ListPreference android:entries="@array/ScreenModeName" android:title="Screen display mode" android:key="ScreenMode" android:summary="Change the screen display mode" android:entryValues="@array/ScreenModeValue"/>
    <SwitchPreference android:title="3 dot menu mode" android:key="3dot_menu" android:summary="Three menu keys increase" android:summaryOn="3:00 menu has been opened" android:summaryOff="3:00've hidden menu"/>
    <ListPreference android:entries="@array/SoundVolumeName" android:title="Sound volume settings" android:key="SoundVolume" android:summary="Appropriate adjustments phone loud sound" android:entryValues="@array/SoundVolumeValue"/>
    <ListPreference android:entries="@array/LocationName" android:title="Network Location Service Engine" android:key="networklocation" android:summary="Choose Baidu or Google engine" android:entryValues="@array/LocationValue"/>
    <SwitchPreference android:title="DisableGMS" android:key="gms_service" android:summary="to disable gms" android:summaryOn="GMS Enabled" android:summaryOff="GMS Disabled"/>
    <SwitchPreference android:title="Lock Screen Weather" android:key="LockScreenWeather" android:summary="Lock screen display weather information" android:summaryOn="Lock screen weather enabled" android:summaryOff="Lock screen weather disabled"/>
    <SwitchPreference android:title="Lock screen pedometer" android:key="LockScreenSteps" android:summary="Lock screen information display pedometer" android:summaryOn="Lock screen pedometer has been shown" android:summaryOff="Lock screen pedometer has been hidden"/>
    <SwitchPreference android:title="Quick Unlock the lock screen (no point OK)" android:key="AutoUnlock" android:summary="In the lock screen is OK to complete the password entry point" android:summaryOn="Quick Unlock enabled" android:summaryOff="Quick Unlock has been disabled"/>
    <SwitchPreference android:title="Turn on screen when a USB connection or disconnection" android:key="NoWakeOnPlugOrUnplug" android:summary="Turn screen on when USB connection or disconnection" android:summaryOn="When connected turn on" android:summaryOff="When connected stays off"/>
    <SwitchPreference android:title="Automatic brightness fine-tuning (+ -5)" android:key="AutoBrightAdjst" android:summary="Enable automatic brightness trim function" android:summaryOn="Automatic brightness trimming has been opened" android:summaryOff="Automatic brightness trimming has been closed"/>
    <SwitchPreference android:title="Status Bar Time centered" android:key="CenterTime" android:summary="Status Bar Time centered" android:summaryOn="Status Bar Time centered open" android:summaryOff="Status Bar Time centered Close"/>
    <SwitchPreference android:title="Double-click the status bar lock screen" android:key="DoubleClickOffScreen" android:summary="Double-click the status bar lock screen" android:summaryOn="Double-click the status bar lock screen has been opened" android:summaryOff="Double-click the status bar has been closed lock screen"/>
    <SwitchPreference android:title="Smart cover lock screen weather information" android:key="LockWeather" android:summary="Weather information is displayed in a holster lock screen" android:summaryOn="Case lock screen to display weather information has been" android:summaryOff="Case lock screen weather information has been hidden"/>
    <SwitchPreference android:title="Smart cover lock screen pedometer" android:key="LockWalkMate" android:summary="Whether the holster lock screen display pedometer" android:summaryOn="Case lock screen pedometer has been shown" android:summaryOff="Pedometers hide leather lock screen"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: [`PreferenceGroup.removePreference`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceGroup.html#removePreference(android.preference.Preference)) -- So, from Java, not XML

Comment: ok, but what would i add in the java code?